# Can't see the alerts I created on Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azureportal

I am creating alerts inside Application Insights on the Azure Portal, but for some reason I am not able to see them. I know the alerts are working because I am getting the emails as expected.

Using the management API I am able to see the alerts:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/microsoft.insights/scheduledQueryRules/{scheduleQueryName}?api-version=2018-04-16
```

What could be preventing them from appearing on the portal? This is my ARM template

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "appInsightsName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "alertEmail": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "utilityActionGroup": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "scheduleQueryName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "monitoringUtilityAlertEnabled": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "name": "[parameters('appInsightsName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "applicationId": "[parameters('appInsightsName')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups",
      "name": "[parameters('utilityActionGroup')]",
      "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
      "location": "Global",
      "properties": {
        "groupShortName": "Utility",
        "enabled": true,
        "emailReceivers": [
          {
            "name": "AlertEmail",
            "emailAddress": "[parameters('alertEmail')]"
          }
        ]
      },
      "dependsOn": []
    },
    {      
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules",
      "name": "[parameters('scheduleQueryName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2018-04-16",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-link: ', resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('appInsightsName')))]": "Resource"
      },
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {
        "description": "Sends an alert when the utility stops sending a trace to app insights",
        "enabled": "[parameters('monitoringUtilityAlertEnabled')]",
        "source": {
          "query": "traces\n| where message == \"Utility Service is alive\"  | where timestamp >= ago(30m) ",
          "authorizedResources": [],
          "dataSourceId": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('appInsightsName'))]",
          "queryType": "ResultCount"
        },
        "schedule": {
          "frequencyInMinutes": 5,
          "timeWindowInMinutes": 5
        },
        "action": {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.Microsoft.AppInsights.Nexus.DataContracts.Resources.ScheduledQueryRules.AlertingAction",
          "severity": "2",
          "aznsAction": {
            "actionGroup": [ "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/actionGroups', parameters('utilityActionGroup'))]" ],
            "emailSubject": "Monitoring Utility Stopped working"
          },
          "trigger": {
            "thresholdOperator": "Equal",
            "threshold": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('appInsightsName'))]",
        "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/actionGroups', parameters('utilityActionGroup'))]"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {  }
}
```

Comment: First you say that you're "creating alerts... on the Azure portal", but then you say you have an ARM template.  Can you clarify which way you're creating them when the issue occurs?  I experience this issue only only when using ARM templates.

Answer (score 0):

As per my test, I create the alert inside application insights via azure portal, and it can appear in the portal.

When check the alert in portal, please make sure that select the correct resource as the one you create alert.
[image]